# Read file inside current directory using Vue

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get text file data located in the same directory where my .vue file is. But it's not returning the text on both chrome and firefox. Instead it's returning following response, which is not the content of my text file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>router-project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Following is my vue file.

```
<template>
  <body>
    <div> hello world </div>
  </body>
</template>

<script>
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;

export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getPoemList(),
  },

  methods: {
   getPoemList () {

      function reqListener () {
         console.log(this.responseText);
      }

      var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
      oReq.open("GET", "hello.txt");
      oReq.send();


    }   // getPoemList function ends
  }     // methods end
}       // export default ends
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Contents of hello.txt are following.

```
hello
```

Comment: Did you try like ./hello.txt? Check relative and absolute paths

Comment: How can this be achieved if you're using Vite instead of webpack?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*I assume you're using Webpack, since you have a `.vue` file (requiring the `vue-loader` Webpack plugin)...*

You can use [`raw-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) to load the `.txt` file as a string.

1. Install `raw-loader` from NPM with:

   ```
   npm i -D raw-loader
   ```
2. In [`<projectroot>/vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js), configure Webpack to use `raw-loader` for `*.txt`:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     //...
     chainWebpack: config => {
       config.module
         .rule('raw')
         .test(/\.txt$/)
         .use('raw-loader')
         .loader('raw-loader')
         .end()
     },
   }
   ```
3. In your component's `.vue` file, use [`import`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import) or [`require`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require) to load `hello.txt`:

   ```
   <script>
   import helloText from './hello.txt';  // OR: const helloText = require('./hello.txt')

   export default {
     //...
     methods: {
       getPoemList () {
         console.log({ helloText });
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: I installed raw-loader.
Created a file <projectroot>/vue.config.js with the above mentioned contents.
Imported text file and tried to log contents of text file. I'm getting following error. 
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: Instead of 
import helloText from './hello.txt';
following worked. 
import helloText from 'raw-loader!./hello.txt';

Comment: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Vite builder (e.g. when using the Vuetify framework) you can load [a static asset as string](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#importing-asset-as-string) without additional dependencies:

```js
<script setup>
import hello from './hello.txt?raw'
const content = ref(hello)
</script>
```

Access it in your method like this:

```js
<script>
export default {
  //...
  methods: {
    getPoemList () {
      console.log(content);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<template>
  <body>
    <div> hello world {{variable}}</div>
  </body>
</template>

<script>
  var $ = require('jquery');
  window.jQuery = $;

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        variable: "",
      }
    },
    mounted() {

      methods: {
        // create a vm variable pointing this
        const vm = this;

        function reqListener() {
          // captures the local value this.responseText to vm (this vuejs) vm.variable
          vm.variable = this.responseText;
          console.log(this.responseText);
        }

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
        oReq.open("GET", "hello.txt");
        oReq.send();


      }
    }
  }

</script>

<style> </style>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [answer].