# Reading txt files in Vue without Webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a file in `@/assets` called `data.txt`. Apparently, I'm unable to `import Data from "@/assets/data.txt"`  and then create a function

```
computed: {
readFile: function(){
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(Data)
    return reader.result
    }
}
```

because I can only import `json` and not `txt` without installing `Webpack`, and then configuring  `raw-loader`, which seems like a massively complicated endeavor to read a simple text file. I also can't explicitly write `reader.readAsText("./src/assets/data.txt")` because I get an error of `TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

I know that I can circumvent this problem by simply making the text file into a `json` file and adding the line `export const data="..."`, but, again, it seems like a rather circuitous solution to simply read a `txt` file.

(And I am aware of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54703169/376936, which is confusing to me, because I don't have a `vue.config.js`, which may be an entirely different problem, but it still doesn't explain why Vue can't read a simple text file without multiple steps. It seems like it's the very simple actions in Vue that cause the most confusion.)

Am I missing something very simple and basic?

Comment: How are you using Vue without a Vue config and a build system? Are you using script tags to load the libraries?

Comment: I do have a build system -- I'm assuming that those are all in my `package.json` and then I instantiate them in my `main.js`. I also have an `.eslintrc.js` and a `babel.config.js`. I use the Vue CLI, but I have no `Vue.config.js`. In general, I `yarn add package-name`, `import Package from "package-name"` and then `Vue.use(package)`

Comment: You need to create the config file

Comment: @Dan I understand that that's what the other answer was -- my question is why it's so convoluted to do, and if there is a simpler way to do what should be one of the most basic actions possible. I can't believe there isn't a way that doesn't require additional plugins.

Comment: Well, adding packages is a very common part of the modern JavaScript tool chain.  If every available tool was included with Webpack, it would bloat installations.  Text file loading is actually probably relatively uncommon in JavaScript projects.  That said, the process is, I think, quite simple when you think about it:  1) `npm install` 2) create the config, 3) Add the loader to the config.  You can probably do all of that in under 1 minute, and the config file is pretty standard.  I think since this is not intuitive, and there's no GUI, it may seem more complex than it is.

Comment: One thing I noticed is you said that unlike json, you couldn't use text files "without installing Webpack and then configuring `raw-loader`". This has me wondering if you realize that Vue CLI already is Webpack.  There is no additional Webpack install to be done, just the loader.

Comment: @Dan I did it. I actually did not realize that Vue CLI is already Webpack, the documentation didn't seem that clear. Thank you for the explanation / clarification.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.  Vue CLI has its own docs, you can read more about Webpack and loaders [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html).  If you want me to put my comments into an answer, let me know.